# The name 'DependencyProperty' does not exist in the current context (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following:

```
using System.Windows;

public static object ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType)
{
  ...
  return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

But VisualStudio isn't finding `DependencyProperty` after I install the `WindowsBase` package. I'm fairly new to `C#` and Visual Studio and I don't understand why Visual Studio isn't seeing the `DependencyProperty` class. In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=netframework-4.8) I can clearly see that it wants the `WindowsBase.dll` assembly, which I have:

[image: Clearly have WindowsBase.dll]

What else could I be missing?

Comment: when you hover over the yellow triangle over windowsBase what does it say?

Comment: Could you please specify target framework?
Right-click on project->properties->Application tab->Target fraemwork:

Comment: @Train It says: ```Package 'WindowsBase 4.6.1055' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.```

Comment: @BasilKosovan Target framework is .NET Core 3.1

Comment: And now you need just to read an error: Package 'WindowsBase 4.6.1055' was restored using '.`NetFramework`....

Comment: Have you tried download the core version `WindowsBase_Core.STW`

Comment: @Train `WindowsBase_Core.STW` id doesn't look like it's an official analogy of full-framework version(only 372 downloads)

Comment: @Eirhardt Do you really need to target this project to `.Net core`. Let's consider using .`Net Framework`

Comment: Try to downgrade to .net core 3.0, I see it's not supported in 3.1 from the docs.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Or just return create a new `public static readonly object UnsetValue;` type yourself.

Comment: @Train I think my issue is that I chose .NET Core instead of .NET Framework as the project backbone as per Basil Kosovan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different target frameworks:

```
 - .NET Framework(1)
 - .NET Core(2)
 - .net Standart(3)
```

1 or 2 could depend on a project which has written on 3, but 1 couldn't depend on 2 or vice versa. Your target framework is  `.NET Core 3.1` and you have an error associated with `WindowsBase` which is written on NET Framework

Comment: since the project is in its early stages I will swap to .NET Framework instead of .NET Core. I believe that will solve the issue. Didn't realize the difference - very new to all this. Thank you for your solution, will report back if I have any more issues.

Comment: @RobertLewis please add a link

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core "The next release after .NET Core 3.0 will be .NET 5. The .NET Framework will be deprecated, and .NET 5 will be the only .NET going forward – hence the removal of the "Core" branding and skipping of version 4 to avoid confusion with the .NET Framework 4.x.[17]"

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you. Good to know this